# R: how to divide a vector of values into fixed number of groups, based on smallest distance?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I think I have a rather simple problem but I can't figure out the best approach. I have a vector with 30 different values. Now I need to divide the vector into 10 groups in such a way that the mean within group variance is as small as possible. the size of the groups is not important, it can anything between one and 21.

Example. Let's say I have vector of six values, that I have to split into three groups:

```
Myvector <- c(0.88,0.79,0.78,0.62,0.60,0.58)
```

Obviously the solution would be:

```
Group1 <-c(0.88)
Group2 <-c(0.79,0.78)
Group3 <-c(0.62,0.60,0.58)
```

Is there a function that gives the same outcome as the example and that I can use for my vector withe 30 values?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do k-means clustering. `kmeans(Myvector,3, algo="Lloyd")` seems to work with your test data.

Comment: Brilliant :-). If you please I will exept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do k-means clustering. Something like this would work

```
kmeans(Myvector,3, algo="Lloyd")
```

Note that I changed the default algorithm to match your desired output. If you read the `?kmeans` help page you will see that there are different algorithms to calculate the different clusters because it's not a trivial computational problem. They might necessarily guarantee optimality.